# How do I create a variable outside a function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I apologize in advance for my confusing question.
I am attempting to write a simple text-based rpg for school, and I went into this with no prior knowledge of python or how to code in it. so after many youtube videos and tutorials and such, I got a pretty good base understanding. So one thing I wanted is for the character to have a name that you set just after the start. so to do this I did this

```
def character_namer ():
    character_name = raw_input("please enter your name: ")
```

the problem is that now my variable 'character_name' can only be used within the def character_namer loop. How do I create a variable outside of that loop that represents 'character_name' so that any time I want to say the characters name I just type 'character_name'. Thanks.

Comment: You have to return that value from the function. But that's such a simple usage for a function, you could just call `raw_input` in its own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return the value

```
def character_namer():
    return raw_input("please enter your name: ")

character_name = character_namer()

print character_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Either return the value within the function like what Paul Rooney suggested, or if you're inside idle or python shell simply do:

```
character_name = raw_input('please enter your name: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's good practice to keep track of the game state in a class. Sure this might be a little over the top for "just" the character name, but it will be much more easy to extend and maintain.

```
class Game(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.character_name = None
    # eventually other important values

  def ask_name(self):
    self.character_name = raw_input('please enter your name: ')

  def play(self):
    self.ask_name()
    print('Hello,' self.character_name)
    # etc ...


game = Game()
game.play()
```